# styling text within an article with hover - but link is on article element

Tags: css

I'm designing a site, where I have  elements with a link on them. I want this so that a visitor can click anywhere on the article to be linked to the page.
The code I have is:

```
<article class="pfitem"><a href="research.php">
<img class="pfcover" src="Images/pfresearch.png" />
<p class="pfcaption">Research Papers</p>
</a></article>
```

I want the text which says "Research" to have a purple background when people hover the article because this is what I have throughout all the text links on the site.
I tried with CSS to style this using the class "pfcap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
.pfitem:hover a .pfcaption{
 background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the background colour now, and I added
text-decoration:none; but I'm still getting an underline when I hover... any fix for that?

Comment: write like this **.pfitem:hover a{text-decoration:none;border:0}**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know if that would work normally, but it didn't work for me - but I realised in my CSS reset I had the hover to be underline. I don't know why that was overwritten w/ my other code, but no this one. When I remove this CSS reset the underline disappears - so your solution might work for others... thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should work:

```
.pfcaption:hover {
    background-color: #d9f;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you testing in? I checked Chrome and IE9 and it looked fine.